# Let $a\in \Bbb C$ with $|a|>1$. Find the image of the unit disk under the analytic function $f(z)=1/(z+a)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

> **Problem 1.4.3:** Let $a \in\Bbb C$ with $|a|>1$. Find the image of the unit disk under the analytic function  $f(z)=\frac{1}{z+a}$.

*My work so far:*   By the definition of the unit disk 
\begin{align} 
D = \{z \in \Bbb C\,∶\,|z|<1\}&\qquad&(i)
\end{align}

Suppose  $w=f(z)=\frac{1}{z+a}$
\begin{align}
w(z+a)&=1&\\
wz+wa&=1&\\
wz&=1-wa&\\
z&=\frac{1-wa}{w}&&(ii)\qquad \text{Put this in }(i)\\
\left\lvert \frac{1-wa}{w}\right\rvert&<1&\\ 
|1-wa|&<|w|&\\
\end{align}
Where $w$: $w$-plane in complex function.

After that, I need help. Thanks

Comment: Problem 1.4.3: Let a ∈C with |a|>1. Find the image of the unit disk under the analytic function  f(z)=1/(z+a)
SOLUTION: - By the definition of the unit disk D = {z ∈ C∶|z|<1}…… (i)
  Suppose  w=f(z)=1/(z+a)
  w(z+a)=1
  wz+wa=1
wz=1-wa
   z=(1-wa)/w  ------------------ (ii)   Put this in (i)
  |(1-wa)/w|<1 
  |1-wa|<|w|
Where w: w-plane in Complex function
After that, need help……. thanks

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

*Sketch:* Now you can write $w=x+yi,\ a=\alpha+\beta i$ with $x,y,\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$ and get $$\lvert 1-(x+yi)(\alpha+\beta i)\rvert^2 <\lvert x+yi\rvert^2\\\lvert 1-\alpha x+\beta y-(\alpha y+\beta x)i\rvert^2<\lvert x+yi\rvert^2$$

Which, after the calcs, turns out to be an inequality in the form $P_{\alpha,\beta}(x,y)<0$, for a suitable real polynomial $P_{\alpha,\beta}(x,y)$ of degree $2$. Then, finding the locus of this inequality in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is an exercise of elementary analytical geometry of $\Bbb R^2$.

If I were you, I'd observe that $$P_{\alpha,\beta}(x,y)=(\alpha^2+\beta^2-1)x^2+(\alpha^2+\beta^2-1)y^2+r_{\alpha,\beta}(x,y)$$ where $\deg r_{\alpha,\beta}\le1$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

> $f(z)=f_2(f_1(z)),$ where $f_1(z)=z+a$ and $f_2(z)=\dfrac1z.$

Observations:
1. $f_1$ translates the unit disk to a disk centered at $a$ with radius $1.$
2. Image of the circle $C$ under $f_2$ is either circle or a line according  to $0\not\in C$ or $0\in C.$